# Debug called functions in matlab

Tags: matlab

Another Matlab debugging question:

Main code:

```
b=3;
a = function_1(b)
```

function_1:

```
function out = function_1(in)
out=in*5
end
```

If i am in the main code, and want to debug function_1, how do i do it? Just placing a breakpoint in the function doesn't work, the code executes without stopping. It seems that i can only place breakpoints in the main code.

Comment: That should work just fine. How are you setting the breakpoint? Is `function_1.m` saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint in the main code a = function_1(b) and it stops there, press step in instead of step over.

Or another way, put a break point in function_1, wait for it to go in.